# Failing to set up my tkinter button function properly to end recursion upon second press of button

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion, conditional-statements, optional-parameters

I'm trying to program a timer app that counts down seconds based on an input in minutes. I have a recursive function that conditionally checks to see what the current time is and increments it (and then reconfigures it as a tkinter Label), and then, if appropriate, calls the function again until the timer hits Zero. This part works, but I decided to attempt to implement a feature where after calling the function once via button press, the button gets reconfigured to be a "Pause Timer" button. I'm close, I think, but I am having trouble getting the timer to stop counting down.

My thinking way to have the function that the tk.Button widget calls with it's "command=" arg be one that accepts a boolean statement, with either True or False, based on whether the button press should pause the timer or let it run again. When you pass False, it's supposed to bypass the recursive part of the function and go to 1).config the button to have it swap back to "Start Timer" and change the "command=" back to passing the original function with the True arg instead, so that it will resume when you push the timer next. In my testing, I was able to get the timer to pause by using a conditional statement based on if the "Set Timer" button was "active" after entering a new time in the Entry field, but that was overwriting the current time, which isn't useful for a pause button.

I'm fairly new to programming. Code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

background = tk.Frame(root)
background.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, columnspan=6, padx=10, pady=10)

lbf1 = tk.LabelFrame(background, text="Lane 1")
lbf1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)

timer1 = tk.Label(lbf1, text="00:00",  bg="#000000", fg="#ff0000", font=38)
timer1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="s", padx=2, pady=2)

ent1 = tk.Entry(lbf1, bg="#cccccc", fg="#000000", justify="center")
ent1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="s", padx=2, pady=2)

def timer1Set():
    try:
        t = str(ent1.get())
    except ValueError:
        t = "00"
    s = "00"
    global time1
    time1 = "{0}:{1}".format(t, s)
    timer1.config(text=time1)
    last = len(ent1.get())
    ent1.delete(0,last)
    startB1.config(state="active")

def timer1Update(toggle=True):
    if toggle == True:
        time1 = str(timer1.cget("text"))
        ctime1 = time1.partition(":")
        cmins1, _, csecs1 = ctime1
        cmins1 = int(cmins1)
        csecs1 = int(csecs1)
        startB1.config(text="Pause Timer", command=lambda:(timer1Update(False)))
        
        if (cmins1 == 0) and ((csecs1 > 0) and (csecs1 < 11)):
            timer1.config(text=str(cmins1) + ":" + ("0" + str(csecs1 - 1)))
            timer1.after(1000, lambda:(timer1Update()))
        elif (cmins1 == 0) and (csecs1 > 0):
            timer1.config(text=str(cmins1) + ":" + str(csecs1 - 1))
            timer1.after(1000, lambda:(timer1Update()))
        elif (cmins1 > 0) and (csecs1 == 0):
            timer1.config(text=str(cmins1 - 1) + ":59")
            timer1.after(1000, lambda:(timer1Update()))
        elif (cmins1 > 0) and ((csecs1 > 0) and (csecs1 < 11)):
            timer1.config(text=str(cmins1) + ":" + ("0" + str(csecs1 - 1)))
            timer1.after(1000, lambda:(timer1Update()))
        elif (cmins1 > 0) and (csecs1 > 0):
            timer1.config(text=str(cmins1) + ":" + str(csecs1 - 1))
            timer1.after(1000, lambda:(timer1Update()))
        else:
            startB1.config(state="active")
            lane1End = tk.Tk()
            L1EndL = tk.Label(lane1End, text="Lane 1 Time Up!")
            L1EndL.pack()
            L1EndB = tk.Button(lane1End, text="Okay", command=lane1End.destroy)
            L1EndB.pack()
            lane1End.mainloop()
    else:
        startB1.config(text="Start Timer", command=lambda:(timer1Update()))
        return None

def z1():
    timer1.config(text="00:00")

setB1 = tk.Button(lbf1, text="Set Time", justify="left", command=timer1Set)
setB1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=2, pady=2)

def setB1state():
    if ent1.get() == "":
        setB1.config(state="disabled")
        setB1.after(1000, setB1state)
    else:
        setB1.config(state="active")
        setB1.after(1000, setB1state)

startB1 = tk.Button(lbf1, text="Start Timer", justify="center", command=lambda:(timer1Update()))
startB1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=2, pady=2)

clearB1 = tk.Button(lbf1, text="Clear", justify="right", command=z1)
clearB1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="n", padx=2, pady=2)

setB1state()

root.mainloop()
```

Specifically, the issue I'm having is with the timer1Update() function. I tried to set the argument "toggle" as True by default with the "=True" bit, but when I push the button "startB1" again after starting the timer the first time, it changes the text on the button to "Pause Timer" like I wanted, but then swaps right back to it after I click the "Pause timer" button that startB1 becomes. I figure it is because the way I'm calling the function is wrong or something. Clicking the "Pause Timer" button again and again just speeds up the timer by setting up multiple recursive calls to the update function.

As you can see in the code above, I tried to set up a boolean "Switch" for the function that would determine what "mode" the button was in when clicked to determine it's behavior, and upon trying that, I got a button that doesn't stop the timer recursion at all, and instead speeds it up by layering more of the recursive function. I expect that I could set up another conditional or reframe the conditional inside of the update function to check some property inside the button to see if it should continue with the recursion or not, but I'm honestly stumped. Any advice?

Comment: I've tried to think of some property that I could examine with the tkinter .cget() function that would be an effective way to determine what the timer should be doing, but I was only able to stop the timer by trying to use an if statement to see if the button had been pressed. I could just add a new button and a new function for that button, but I was really hoping to have the button toggle between start and pause, and I want to avoid having too many extra buttons. Also, this is just one lane of a multi-lane app, and so each function is getting repeated 6 times, so it's best if condensed...

Comment: It is better to separate the logic into two functions: one for start and stop the countdown, one for the countdown loop.

Comment: maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361523/tkinter-after-second-and-minute/74361677#74361677

Comment: Every time you press the button you summon a new function which all dynamics managed by inside of function and you almost have no control over it. May be you can make it by inner functions but this isn't adviced in programming.

Comment: Why are you using duplicated TK() and mainloop()? You can write one TK() and tk.mainloop() for entire script and then use Toplevel() for L1EndL. You will have to write another function for pause

Comment: @toyotaSupra, thank you for that insight, I didn't realize I could do that. In implementing that change, I fixed another issue that I was having where the pop-ups weren't closing when you closed the root window.